# apache-spark-Cost Based Optimizer(CBO) stats are not used while evaluating query plans in Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to leverage CBO for getting better plan results for few critical queries run thru spark-sql or thru thrift server using jdbc driver. Following settings added to spark-defaults.conf {code}

```
 spark.sql.cbo.enabled true spark.experimental.extrastrategies 
 intervaljoin spark.sql.cbo.joinreorder.enabled true {code}
```

The tables that we are using are not partitioned.

Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/cbo.html

Comment: Did you collect statistics?

Comment: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", true)

Comment: What is your source tables? Hive?

Answer (score 0):

You provide little detail. Check if all steps have been followed as set out below pls.

From Spark 2.2 when I last looked at this excellent article: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/spark-sql-cost-based-optimizer/read

the following:

**Spark SQL implementation**

At the time of writing (2.2.0 released) Spark SQL Cost Based Optimization is disabled by default and can be activated through spark.sql.cbo.enabled property. When enabled, it applies in: filtering, projection, joins and aggregations, as we can see in corresponding estimation objects from org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.statsEstimation package: FilterEstimation, ProjectEstimation, JoinEstimation and AggregateEstimation.

Even if at first glance the use of estimation objects seems to be conditioned only by the configuration property, it's not always the case. The Spark's CBO is applied only when the statistics about manipulated data are known (read more about them in the post devoted to Statistics in Spark SQL). This condition is expressed by EstimationUtils method:

```
def rowCountsExist(conf: SQLConf, plans: LogicalPlan*): Boolean =
  plans.forall(_.stats(conf).rowCount.isDefined)
```

The filtering is an exception because it's checked against the number of rows existence:

```
if (childStats.rowCount.isEmpty) return None
```

The statistics can be gathered by the execution of **ANALYZE TABLE $TABLE_NAME COMPUTE STATISTICS** command before the processing execution. When ANALYZE command is called, it's executed by:
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AnalyzeTableCommand#run(SparkSession) that updates

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog statistics of processed data.
```

The only problem with ANALYZE command is that it can be called only for Hive and in-memory data stores.

Also, CBO does not work properly with Partitioned Hive Parquet tables; CBO only gives the size and not the number of rows estimated.